# Do we take the Mitzva to eat Healthy seriously?

Tags: health

I've seen my Rabbi serve candy and chemically-laden food to their children. Why don't they follow the Rambam and his diet? Is oneg Shabbos (Shabbos party) docheh the importance of eating healthy, like the Be'er Hagolah, Chinuch, Ritvah, Tur, Gemara, Rambam, Rabbeinu Yonah, Mishna Berurah, Kitzur Shulchan Aruch, Vayikra Rabah, Elya Rabba, Pri Megadim, Kaf Hachaim, all discuss?

Are there any ways to be dan l'kaf zechus on them for not eating healthy? Is being "normal" and not a "health freak" a heter to go against Chazal?

Any sources supporting either side would be appreciated.

Comment: Did chazal say no candy ever?

Comment: So according to your logic smoking ounce in a while is okay even though it violates שמרתם את נפשותיכם

Comment: Who is "we" ?   (15 char)

Comment: @Truth common that's a loaded question, maybe it only violates that prohibition if you smoke often

Comment: There is also a concept of שומר פתאים השם, that we are permitted to do certain activities that involve a slight risk and which are commonly done (eating some candy would presumably fall into that category) and rely on Hashem to guard us against those slight risks.

Comment: Where is this concept from?

Comment: @Truthseeker "_Where is this concept from?_" If you're referring to "שומר פתאים השם" that Meir brought up, [Hebrew Wikipedia](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%A0%D7%A4%D7%A9#%D7%99%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%94_-_%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%A9%D7%94) cites R. Moshe Feinstein (in [Igros Moshe Vol 5, in the Yoreh De'ah section, No. 49](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=919&pgnum=67), referencing [Shabbat 129b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shabbat.129b.5?lang=bi&lang2=en)) and R. Ovadia Yosef (in Yechaveh Da'at, Part 5, No. 39).

Comment: "_I've seen my Rabbi serve candy and chemically-laden food to their children. Why don't they follow the Rambam and his diet?_" Where does Rambam (and his diet) forbid eating candy and chemically-laden food?

Comment: "_Is oneg Shabbos (Shabbos party) docheh the importance of eating healthy, like the Be'er Hagolah, Chinuch, Ritvah, Tur, Gemara, Rambam, Rabbeinu Yonah, Mishna Berurah, Kitzur Shulchan Aruch, Vayikra Rabah, Elya Rabba, Pri Megadim, Kaf Hachaim, all discuss?_" That's a lot of name dropping. How about citing/quoting places where they actually discuss the importance of eating healthy?

Comment: The Ritvah says one should not eat any unhealthy food - Meseches Shavuos 27a.

Comment: @Truthseeker (1) Then, you should edit that into the question (with a more specific place, of which of the 4 entries [there](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ritva_on_Shevuot.27a) you're referring to, _at least_) . (2) I see him mentioning there "bad things" Where does he talk about "_unhealthy_ food"? How does he define it? (If that is the only actual source you're going to bring, then answers to those should also be edited into the question.)

Comment: https://torasavigdor.org/rav-avigdor-miller-on-cigarettes-and-first-steps/